# New user added but having error in AIX 7.1

Tags: unix, user-management, aix

I newly add a user name perfmgr in AIX 7.1 using smitty, however when I try to change the password it output and error as below:

```
# passwd perfmgr
Changing password for "perfmgr"
3004-616 User "perfmgr" does not exist.
3004-709 Error changing password for "perfmgr".
#
```

Im using root to run above command.

This is quite weird since I can see this user perfmgr are available under /etc/passwd:

```
# grep perfmgr /etc/passwd
perfmgr:*:208:1::/space/perfmgr:/usr/bin/ksh
#
```

Then I try to remove this user using smitty, but same error occurred again,

> User "perfmgr" does not exist.

Need advise for this issue since cannot found the correct way to remove or fix this user.

Comment: What did IBM support say?

Comment: Was the user `perfmgr` successfully created? Can you do `id perfmgr` or grep the user from `/etc/security/user`?

Comment: @Alvin Sim  Thanks Alvin, I already found the issue, the issue is there are no registry stated under the perfmgr user in /etc/security/user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, the issue is there are no registry line for user perfmgr under /etc/security/user file.

```
perfmgr:
        admin = false
        registry = files
```

However, before that I fix the other thing where my perfmgr are not sync with other file using below command,

```
pwdck -y perfmgr
```

Then, after I run this command I proceed to manually create 'registry=files' line under /etc/security/user file as above.

Hope this helps other user which encountered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Copying my comment from a similar Stackover flow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585252/new-user-added-but-having-error-in-aix-7-1).

Do you use LDAP? If so, it may be searching for the user in LDAP. We just had a similar problem and using an explicit `-R files` helped. Even if you don't use LDAP use `-R`: `passwd -R files perfmgr` or `passwd -R compat permgr`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, however we are not using LDAP in this server.

Comment: Even if you are not, force it to look for the user in the local files by using `-R files`.